# fatfs f_write returns FR_DISK_ERR when passing a pointer to data in a mail queue

Tags: embedded, stm32, freertos, cmsis, fatfs

I'm trying to use FreeRTOS to write ADC data to SD card on the STM32F7 and I'm using V1 of the CMSIS-RTOS API. I'm using mail queues and I have a struct that holds an array.

```
typedef struct
{
     uint16_t data[2048];
} ADC_DATA;
```

on the ADC half/Full complete interrupts, I add the data to the queue and I have a consumer task that writes this data to the sd card. My issue is in my Consumer Task, I have to do a memcpy to another array and then write the contents of that array to the sd card.

```
void vConsumer(void const * argument)
{   
    ADC_DATA *rx_data;

    for(;;)
    {   
        writeEvent = osMailGet(adcDataMailId, osWaitForever);

        if(writeEvent.status == osEventMail)
        {
            // write Data to SD
             rx_data =  writeEvent.value.p;
             memcpy(sd_buff, rx_data->data, sizeof(sd_buff));
             if(wav_write_result == FR_OK)
             {
                 if( f_write(&wavFile, (uint8_t *)sd_buff, SD_WRITE_BUF_SIZE, (void*)&bytes_written) == FR_OK)
                    {
                        file_size+=bytes_written;
                    }
             } 

            osMailFree(adcDataMailId, rx_data);

        }
}
```

This works as intended but if I try to change this line to

```
f_write(&wavFile, (uint8_t *)rx_data->data, SD_WRITE_BUF_SIZE, (void*)&bytes_written) == FR_OK)
```

so as to get rid of the memcpy, f_write returns `FR_DISK_ERR`. Can anyone help shine a light on why this happens, I feel like the extra memcpy is useless and you should just be able to pass the pointer to the queue straight to f_write.

Answer (score 0):

So just a few thoughts here:

### memcpy

Usually I copy only the necessary amount of data. If I have the size of the actual data I'll add a boundary check and pass it to `memcpy`.

### Your problem

I am just guessing here, but if you check the struct definition, the data field has the type uint16_t and you cast it to a byte pointer. Also the [FatFs documentation](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/doc/write.html) expects a void* for the type of buf.

EDIT: Could you post more details of *sd_buff*